# How to resize page content based on iFrame size

Tags: html, iframe, responsiveness

I wonder is it possible to resize content of page based on iframe size? So for instance

```
<iframe width="100" height="300" src="http://example.com/file.html"></iframe>
```

and

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="http://example.com/file.html"></iframe>
```

Should both resize inner content accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

If the content inside the iframe is set to width:100% yes.